# Increase minumum value distance between Integers in Array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting

I would like the increase the minimum 'distance' between values in an array. For example, if I have the array

44,45,47,51,65,66

I would like the minimum 'distance' to be 2. So, the desired output would be

44,46,48,51,65,67

I've tried doing something like

```py
prevValue = array[0]
array.pop(0)

for a in array:
  if(prevValue + 1 >= a):
    a += 1
```

this wasn't the entire code as I had create temp arrays to not mess up the original one. But, this logic does not work.

Has anybody done anything similar? I was looking at np.arrange() but that wasn't the desired use case.

Thank you!

Comment: This was a relatively simple problem, but for your next question you should probably provide a [mcve].  Providing code that is just an approximation for what you actually tried doesn't really help anyone, since it makes it harder for anyone to try the same thing that you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `a += 1` only modifies your local variable named `a`; it would not modify any elements in a list.  Here is one way to do what you want:

```py
list1 = [44, 45, 47, 51, 65, 66]

list2 = []
prev = None
for a in list1:
  if prev and prev + 1 >= a:
    a = prev + 2
  list2.append(a)
  prev = a

print(list2)
```

They are actually called "lists", not "arrays", in Python.  Using the correct search terms might help you find answers better on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try (*assuming the `lst` is sorted*):

```py
lst = [44, 45, 47, 51, 65, 66]

distance = 2

for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    diff = lst[i] - lst[i - 1]
    if diff < distance:
        lst[i] += distance - diff

print(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
[44, 46, 48, 51, 65, 67]
```

---

For `distance = 5`:

```py
[44, 49, 54, 59, 65, 70]
```